# Improving the layout of my Android application

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

In my application, I've implemented a descendant navigation.
And then in my pages, I've implemented ListViews. How can I improve the UI from simple list views from simple list like

```
ITEM 1
ITEM 2
ITEM 3
```

to this:

```
********    ********    ********    ********
* itm1 *    * itm2 *    * itm3 *    * itm4 *
*      *    *      *    *      *    *      *
********    ********    ********    ********
```

and scrollable?  The items are horizontally aligned. I was thinking of GridView also.
But can GridView be customized to display it in a single line only?

Comment: you can use gridview instead of listview for this ..

Comment: can i customized GridView to display it in single line? is Carousel like view is implemented using GridView?

Comment: if you want to implement the corousel means just go for gallery view. in that you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the items in a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with horizontal orientation that is inside a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

There is also an android class [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html), but it's deprecated in api level 16.